# f is continuous iff its graph is closed

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the following exercises from Munkres:

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$: let $Y$ be compact Hausdorff. Then $f$ is continuous iff the graph

$$G_f=\{x\times f(x): x\in X\} \text{ is closed.}$$

$\implies$

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function and assume that $f(X)=Y$ such that $Y$ is compact and Hausdorff. Note by continuity of $f$ we have that $X\times Y$ is Hausdorff. Consider the subpsace topology with basis elements

$$G_f\cap (A\times B).$$

Where $(A\times B)$ is open in $X\times Y$. Note that open sets in the subspace topology will be of the form $f^{-1}(B)\times B$. Note that the subspace topology is also Hausdorff. Consider an open covering of $G_f\subset \cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}f^{-1}(B_i)\times B_i$. By compactness of $Y$ then there exists a finite covering $\cup_{i=1}^{n}B_i$ but this implies a finite covering of  $\cup_{i=1}^{n}f^{-1}(B_i)\times B_i$ of $G_f$, implying compactness. In hausdorff compactness implies closed; thus, $G_f$ is closed.

For the other direction:

Let $G_f$ be closed. Consider an open set $A\subset Y$ and the restriction of the product space to $X\times f(A^C)$. Consider $G_f\cap X\times f(A^C)$, which is closed. Since the projection

$$\pi_1: X\times Y\rightarrow X, $$

is a closed mapping when $Y$ is compact, then $\pi_1(G_f\cap X\times f(A^C))=f^{-1}(A^C)$ is closed. It follows that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.

I am not as confident on the first portion of the proof. Are there any mistakes in my logic?

I am also trying to prove the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ via the set $X=\mathbb{R}^{n}\cup\{\infty\}$ with the topology generated by the basis of standard balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and sets of the form $U_r=\{\infty\} \cup \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:|x|>r\}$. I figured take an open covering of $X$ then it must contain at least one element of $U_r$ then only need to worry about $\{x\in X: |x|\le r\}$, but this is compact in the subspace topology so can find a finite covering of standard balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ getting me compactness of $X$. Does this make sense?

Instead of solutions can hints be provided as to the correct approach if one of my methods is flawed.

Comment: In the first part of your proof, please elaborate on how you know that the required open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ exists.  It's not obvious to me how that follows from the Hausdorff property.

Comment: @RobertShore I have expanded my reasoning for the existence of $U$.

Comment: @RobertShore I am banking on the compactness of $Y$ for this covering of $f(X)$. The issue that pops in my head is that this covering might cover all of $Y$ therefore making it impossible to find a covering that allows space for such a neighborhood $U$.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is correct as stated.  In $\Bbb R$, consider the open set $U= \Bbb R \setminus \{ x \}$.  Even though $\Bbb R$ is a Hausdorff space, there is no neighborhood of $x$ that is disjoint from $U$.  Nor does compactness help -- instead of $\Bbb R$, consider $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @RobertShore I have updated my proof to consider limit points.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction in the three statements $(V \times U) \cap G_f \neq \emptyset$, $(V \times W) \cap G_f \neq \emptyset$, $(V \times U) \cap (V \times W) = \emptyset$. And it doesn't look as though you've used continuity of $f$ in either attempt to show $G_f$ is closed.

Comment: @aschepler I figured since I have two open balls that are disjoint in Y that intersect $G_f$ and are on top of each other then them both intersecting $G_f$ in $Y$ is not possible, but in my mind I am thinking of $\epsilon$ balls in $R$ and figured that might extend. I will think about this problem again.

Comment: Why is the first sentence in "$\implies" "such that $Y$ is compact Hausdorff", even though this is already assumed by theorem statement?